# man page for .jar file?

Tags: java, jar, package

So, I made a jar file, test.jar
Is there a way to make man page for jar file?
Like,

> man java -jar test.jar

or

> man test.jar

Comment: Choosing either test or the runnable jar you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man is Unix specific and knows nothing about java and your jar.

To read manifest or some help file in your jar you can try something like

unzip -q -c test.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF > cat

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a man page in unix is to write it as text, with the help of a template.

Let's say we want to create a man page for **myprog**.

```
.\" Manpage for myprog.
.\" Contact myprog@ya.ru to thanks
.TH man 1 "20 March 2018" "1.0" "myprog man page"
.SH NAME
myprog \- Watch for directories, file or url change
.SH SYNOPSIS
myprog [user]
.SH DESCRIPTION
Watch for file changes into directories , file(s), or url.
myprog is beautiful

(..)


.SH OPTIONS
myprog  [url|file|(empty=folder)]
.SH SEE ALSO
inotify(7) my_otherprog(1)
.SH BUGS
Mail function is off.
.SH AUTHOR
MYPROG myprog@ya.ru
```

Edit as needed, then name the file as **myprog.1**, if you want it to be in category 1.

Man categories are as follow:

```
1   General commands
2   System calls
3   Library functions, covering in particular the C standard library
4   Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5   File formats and conventions
6   Games and screensavers
7   Miscellanea
8   System administration commands and daemons
```

Then just copy your man page **myprog.1** into the the appropriate folder:

```
sudo cp myprog.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/
```

To update the man database:

```
sudo mandb
```

All done!

Your man page can now be seen for all users with:

```
man myprog
```

[image]

To later update just replace again.